# Select multiple columns from a subquery in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, subquery

I know how to select a field from subquery:

```
SELECT 
    ID, fck, f1, 
    (SELECT f2 FROM tbl2 Y WHERE Y.ID = T.fck) AS f2
FROM 
    tbl1 T
```

If I need to select two columns from the subquery, actually I do:

```
SELECT 
    ID, fck, f1, 
    (SELECT f2 FROM tbl2 Y WHERE Y.ID = T.fck) AS f2, 
    (SELECT f3 FROM tbl2 Y WHERE Y.ID = T.fck) AS f3
FROM 
    tbl1 T
```

There is a way to avoid two subqueries? Something like:

```
SELECT 
    ID, fck, f1, 
    (SELECT f2, f3 FROM tbl2 Y WHERE Y.ID = T.fck) AS f2, f3
FROM 
    tbl1 T
```

Database is SQL Server 2008 R2.

I know this simple example may be rewritten using JOINs, but there are real cases where there aren't equivalent forms using JOIN.

Comment: This is a simple `join` behavior. If you need `TOP 1` - use @Giorgos Betsos approach

Comment: I search exactly the equivalent question of this for mysql

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can use `OUTER APPLY`:

```
SELECT t1.ID, t1.fck, t1.f1, t3.f2, t3.f3
FROM tbl1 AS t1
OUTER APPLY (
   SELECT f2, f3 
   FROM tbl2 AS t2 
   WHERE t2.ID = t1.fck) AS t3
```

The `SELECT` clause contains scalar values, so it can't handle subqueries returning more than field, or multiple records of one field.

Comment: Thank you. Looking for that since months. Will try it and give you my feedback.

Comment: This got me out of trouble with an `update` query. I needed a correlated sub query to fetch a random row from another table, and I needed to use more than one column from the random row. Thanks

Comment: @Giorgos Betsos > And for mysql ?

Answer (score 2):

A correlated subquery is used to get a single value, but you can simply turn your subquery into a join to do what you need:

```
SELECT T.ID, T.fck, T.f1, Y.f2, Y.f3
FROM tbl1 T
INNER JOIN tbl2 Y ON Y.ID = T.fck
```

As with any join, you also need to determine whether you need an `INNER JOIN` versus `OUTER JOIN`, and make sure you understand whether the relationship between tables is 1..1, 1..N, etc., but in general this is how to get multiple fields from a related table.